# Can not load a txt to NSDictionary

Tags: ios

When I load a txt file in my app, i use the code below:

```
NSString *txtPath = [mgzPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",mgz]];
NSMutableDictionary *dict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:txtPath];
```

I can make sure file is exist in the path and in the txt is some json string.
However i get null value, Can anyone tell me why?

JSON string for reference

```
{
    "data": {
        "mag_index": {
            "month": 1,
            "id": "1",
            "year": 2013
        },
        "mag_catalog": [
            {
                "id": "8a22e94a45448e0a01454fb8831d03bb",
                "author": "",
                "title": "",
                "image_url": "1397201623655_718.jpg"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Comment: Check weather the `json` is array or dictionary. If it is array `dict ` will be nil. So try changing `NSMutableDictionary` to `NSMutableArray` and check

Comment: Please post your JSON string

Comment: You may want to `NSLog` your `txtPath` to see if it points to the place where the file is.

Comment: {
  "data" : {
    "mag_index" : {
      "month" : 1,
      "id" : "1",
      "year" : 2013
    },
    "mag_catalog" : [
      {
        "id" : "8a22e94a45448e0a01454fb8831d03bb",
        "author" : "",
        "title" : "",
        "image_url" : "1397201623655_718.jpg"
      }
    ]
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

You have to parse the content of that JSON, can't just simply read the file content. Do something like:

```
    NSString *txtPath = [mgzPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.txt",mgz]];
    NSData *JSONData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:txtPath];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableDictionary * dict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

Comment: Correct. InitWithContentsOfFile expects the file to be a plist, not JSON.

Comment: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (Unable to convert data to string around character 57.) UserInfo=0x18c49d50 {NSDebugDescription=Unable to convert data to string around character 57.